# Exercise on queue in java

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;

public class TestQueueTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int counter = 0;
        String color = " ";
        String ticket;
        int listSize = 5;
        int attendants = 2;

        String[] colors = {"red", "blue", "yellow"};

        Queue<String> tickets = new LinkedList<>();

       while(tickets.size() < listSize)
       {
        
        color = colors[random.nextInt(3)];
        ticket = color + (random.nextInt(listSize) + 1);
        tickets.add(ticket);
       
       }
       
    }   
}
```

I am working on a college exercise in Java, and after generating these random passwords, I need to put them in a queue list, and the exercise requires using only one list.

I need to organize it so that the red passwords come first, the blue ones second, and the yellow ones third.

Example: (red1, red5, blue3, blue7, yellow8)

Which method can I use to organize this using only one list?

Comment: Keep track of where in the list the first (or last) of each color is.  Or, more accurately, where you would want to add an item of each color.

Comment: Use a `priorityQueue` with a custom comparator based on color. Queues are FIFO, so they won’t provide the ordering you want.